# How to define and execute GraphQL query with filter

Tags: graphql

So the thing i try to do is, retrieve filtered data from the Database (MongoDB in my situation) using GraphQL.

Speaking in "MySQL language" how to implement the `where` clause in GraphQL?

I followed this tutorial :
https://learngraphql.com/basics/using-a-real-data-source/5

Query with filter was defined like this :

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Queries",
  fields: {
    authors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Author),
      resolve: function(rootValue, args, info) {
        let fields = {};
        let fieldASTs = info.fieldASTs;
        fieldASTs[0].selectionSet.selections.map(function(selection) {
          fields[selection.name.value] = 1;
        });
        return db.authors.find({}, fields).toArray();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The tricky part here is the `info` parameter in the `resolve` function. Some explanations i've found here : http://pcarion.com/2015/09/26/graphql-resolve/

So it is [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (Abstract Syntax Tree)

Can anyone please provide some basic real-life example code that would show how to **define** and **execute** the following query : 
**Get all authors where name == John**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to examine the AST. That would be awfully laborious.

All you need to do is define an **argument** on the `author` field. This is the second paramenter of the resolver, so you can check for that arguement and include it in the Mongo query.

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Queries",
  fields: {
    authors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Author),

      // define the arguments and their types here
      args: {
        name: { type: GraphQLString }
      },

      resolve: function(rootValue, args, info) {
        let fields = {};
        // and now you can check what the arguments' values are
        if (args.name) {
          fields.name = args.name
        }
        // and use it when constructing the query
        return db.authors.find(fields, fields).toArray();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: As a little overview what other filters/arguments are possible, here's an article how we use arguments to implement filters at Graphcool: https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3

Comment: Here is my article about flexible filtering capabilities that can be added to the GraphQL API. All this while keeping the type safety and run-time validation that we get out-of-the-box from GraphQL. https://dev.to/mgustus/filtering-graphql-query-using-typescript-and-typeorm-2l49