# How to add List in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I am new to graphQL. My Ghapgh Ql query wants following format `{"offers": false, "new": true, "favourites": true}` where offers, new, favourites are of Filters in java class. Query can have any number of such filters. How to write graphql query which will accept list of filters and build query like above. I tried by writting above hadcoded query.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417363/how-to-define-and-execute-graphql-query-with-filter) is similar to yours in that it discusses the concept of filtering with GraphQL. There is also a comment on the first answer that leads to some GraphCool documentation that discusses their approach to filtering. ([GraphCool Docs](https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3/)). I'm not super knowledgeable on the Java front so hopefully this is still helpful.

Generally though, you can include optional params in your query, that if present filter your result in your resolve.

Resolves take args as the second argument. Depending on how many potential filters you would like to provide, you can choose the correct implementation.

Two options are, 1) have a param `filter` that takes a list of filters. (This is similar to GraphCool; 2) Just use variable names as args and filter on those things.

So for your example, I'm not really sure what your models look like exactly or what type of DB/ORM you are using, but if you went with option 2, you can essentially in your resolve just filter the result (JS sorry I'm not much of a java expert).

```
resolve: (_, args, context) => {
    const result = someDbInteractionForResult()
    result.filter( (item) => {
        for (const [filter, value] of Object.entries(args)) {
             const passFilter = value === item.filter;
             if (!passFilter) {
                 return false;
             }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is still a similar approach to passing the filters in in the GraphCool manner. I think the decision is just that if you have other `args` that you will also include. If so, then you will want to block off your filters in its own object so it's easier to separate your concerns.